# Does this typecast the return value to a const? bool foo() const { return bar; }?

Tags: c++

Here's the snippet in title (more readable)  `bool foo() const { return bar; }?`

If not, is it different from `const foo() {return bar;}`? Or is it the same thing as saying the argument the function takes is a constant?

I've tried scouring cppreference and can't find anything.

Comment: There are no casts in this code, so the literal answer is simply “no”. The question is about a **conversion**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` in the first code snippet:

```
bool foo() const { return bar; }
```

Means that the method does not modify the instance of the class that owns the method. Let's add some more code to make this clear:

```
bool bar = true;

struct Foo {
    bool foo() const { return bar; }
};

int main() {
    const Foo f;
    f.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When `f.foo()` is called the instance `f` is not modified. That is the meaning of the `const` in your snippet. It has nothing to do with the return value `bar`

The second code snippet is a compiler error. It would return a `const foo` if it had an identifier

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
class Foo {
public:

    // This method is const.  
    size_t const_method() const {
    
        // which implies that 'this' is const
        const Foo* pthis = this;

        // so we can read values from the classes member variables,
        // but we can't modify any values. 
        return this->m_bar.size();

        // i.e. the following code would fail, because we can't change
        // any of the member variables.
        // 
        // m_bar.push_back(10);
    }

    // This method is mutable.  
    void mutable_method() {
    
        // which implies that 'this' is non-const
        Foo* pthis = this;

        // so we can make changes here
        m_bar.push_back(10);
    }

    // const on the return type is only used when dealing with references.
    // (or pointer types).
    // In this case, if we returned a `std::vector<int>&` here, then
    // code outside of this class could modify the values of m_bar. 
    // This would be bad. It would break encapsulation.
    // So instead, we return a const reference to the variable, which
    // means it can be read, but not modified.
    const std::vector<int>& bar() {
       return m_bar;
    }
    
    // const on return arguments when dealing with value types is 
    // meaningless. return values are rvalues, which implies const. 
    // So here, the const is entirely superfluous. 
    const size_t meaningless() {
        return m_bar.size();
    }

    

private:
    std::vector<int> m_bar;
};
```